# Is "and you" an example of endophora

Tags: terminology

If I were to tell someone to "stand up" and then, after a beat, say "and you" to another person, is that "and you" endophoric?  There's nothing in the first phrase being referred to, it's more the first phrase itself that is being referenced - obviously I would expect different results if I said "put your hands in the air", "and you".

If not endophora, is there a word for this?

Comment: The command _Stand up!_ is vague insofar as the understood subject can be singular or plural. For that reason, I would be cautious about declaring the example an instance of anaphora. The continuation _...And you!_ is concrete, since it would likely include physical pointing or a head-nod. But in such a case, such reference is deictic in nature, which would mean one is not dealing with endophora in the strict sense of being present in the linguistic context. In other words, the term _deixis_ or _deictic reference_ may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Note as well that the ellipsis mechanism of stripping/gapping is involved.  The continuation _...And you_ is short for _And you <stand up>._

Comment: Thank you Tim. Great help